# why dereferences of references to non-copyable data do not have the O permission to avoid double-frees in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust and when I reading a book (https://rust-book.cs.brown.edu/ch04-05-ownership-recap.html), it says

> Dereferences of references to non-copyable data do not have the O permission to avoid double-frees

> The O permission represents ownership of an object. There can only exist one owner of an object, so it is important that references cannot transfer ownership of non-copyable types like String. If two variables thought they owned the same string, then they would both attempt to deallocate it, causing a double-free.

consider we have the code below:

```rust
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let v_ref: &Vec<i32> = &v;
    let v2 = *v_ref;
    // drop(v2);
    // drop(v);
```

the compiler would complain that:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*v_ref` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/main.rs:32:14
   |
32 |     let v2 = *v_ref;
   |              ^^^^^^ move occurs because `*v_ref` has type `Vec<i32>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

but If we directly declare a variable v2 and then assign v to v2, what happens?

```rust
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let v2 = v;
```

it works fine , because `vec` moved. so there isn't double-free?( is it will drop v and v2 ?)

I'm confused that **why** we use derefernces of references, the value it refers to  won't **move** like code above to prevent double-free ?

Is this a specific rule in Rust? Is it to make the code flow clearer (by explicitly performing moves to avoid accidental moves through dereferencing)? Do I just need to remember and adhere to  it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it works fine , because `vec` moved. so there isn't double-free?( is it will drop v and v2 ?)

No, there is no double-free.  Moving from a variable marks it as "moved from" which is a very similar state to "uninitialized" (nearly identical in terms of semantics; they mostly differ in what the compiler tells you if you try to use them for anything other than the target of an assignment).  So `v` gets marked "moved from" and `v2` now owns the value.  `v` can no longer be accessed, and no drop glue will run for it when it goes out of scope.

> I'm confused that why we use derefernces of references, the value it refers to won't move like code above to prevent double-free ?

You can't move out of a reference for many reasons.  One is practical: if you pass a reference into a function and the function moves the value out of it, there is no way for that function to signal back that the value is now gone.  Another is semantic: giving someone a shared reference to a value doesn't give them permission to take the value.

There is a kind of special case though: exclusive references (`&mut`).  Similar to the shared reference case, you can't communicate that the referent was taken, so in general a simple move won't work.  However, you *are* allowed to "steal" the value *if you leave behind a valid value!*  This is the premise behind the [`take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.take.html) and [`replace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.replace.html) functions.

```
let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3];
let v_ref = &mut v;

// The following line takes the Vec from v via the reference,
// replacing it with an empty one.
let v2 = std::mem::take(v_ref);

assert_eq!(&v2[..], &[1, 2, 3]);
assert!(v.is_empty());
```